# Visual Studio, added DLL reference but type not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dotnetzip

I'm new to Visual Studio and Windows, trying to figure out how to include a 3rd party lib into my vb.net project. I'm using VS2010 "free edition", i've added the required DLL file: Ionic.Zlib.dll and can see it under the references recent tab. The type "ZipFile" is still not  resolving but should be according to the readme. Is there something else I need to do to make VS aware of the DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add a [`Imports` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx) at the top of the source file in order to be able to use a type without declaring the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 2):

you need to write on the top of the file

in c#:

using Your_namespace;

**in vb:**

imports Your_namespace

Comment: From the question: "i've added the required DLL file: Ionic.Zlib.dll and can see it under the references recent tab"

Comment: At least get the VB.NET syntax right. It is `Imports` and not `Import` and there is no `;` at the end of statements.